# Json web service - NULL as values

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a c# web service with the following definition:

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "BCryptLogin")]
    LoginResponse BCryptLogin(LoginData logindata);
```

And the actual function is

```
    public LoginResponse BCryptLogin(LoginData logindata)
    {
        string login = logindata.login;
        string password = logindata.password;

        // code be here
    }
```

**When trying to access the "logindata.login" I get a NullReferenceException:**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=LoginService
StackTrace:
   at LoginService.LoginService.BCryptLogin(LoginData logindata) in C:\services\LoginService\LoginService\LoginService.svc.cs:line 74
   at SyncInvokeBCryptLogin(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

This is my first attempt at POST web service and I am fairly clueless :S What is going wrong?

My testing request looks like this:

```
{"login":"username","password":"password"}
```

(also tried)

```
{"LoginData":{"login":"username","password":"password"}}
```

And the LoginData object is defined like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class LoginData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string login { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's at line 74?  (LoginService.svc.cs:line 74)  Attach a debugger and see what's null.  Add tracing, use fiddler.

Comment: Have you stepped through to see if `logindata` is `null`?

Comment: Sounds like your logindata object is null.

Comment: bryanmac: Line 74 is string login = logindata.login;

Comment: post_erasmus, makp3rry: Yes, logindata looks to be null. I don't know why =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is expecting an object, but your passing two values.

```
{"login":"username","password":"password"}
```

You need to create an object in JavaScript and pass it to your function.

```
var LoginData = {};
LoginData.login = "username";
LoginData.password = "password";
```

Then pass this object to your method in your JSON request, using the following syntax.

```
var jsonRequest = {logindata: LoginData};
```

**NOTE:** *The parameter name on your method "logindata" must be the same in your JSON call, it's case sensitive.*

I suggest you use [JSON.org lib](https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) to convert your object into a valid JSON request.

```
JSON.stringify(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: I am not using JavaScript, currently I am handcrafting the requests with RESTClient. I tried {"LoginData":{"login":"username","password":"password"}} too, no affect. LoginData remains null.

Comment: Gotcha, still you should be passing an object... as of right now your not passing a "logindata" parameter as your method expects.  Also, your object "LoginData" should also have the meta attribute "[DataContract]" applied.

Comment: What would the right kind of LoginData-object look like as JSON then? And my LoginData object did have the DataContract-attribute, just didn't copypaste it right :p

Comment: Try changing the capitalization of `LoginData`: `{"logindata":{"login":"username","password":"password"}}`